# Nginx - Restrict/Deny IP for all locations under a server

Tags: nginx, configuration, ip

I am looking to deny a particular IP from Nginx for all the locations under a server configuration.

e.g.

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;  
    location / {
        root /data/www;
        deny 127.0.0.1;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root /data;
        deny 127.0.0.1;
    }
}
```

In this approach, I will have to provide deny or allow for each location.  Is it possible to do this at server level, which would apply to all locations?

Comment: Have you read docs? You easily could use `deny` on server level.

Comment: I did some googling but did not find a definitive answer.  My bad.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Nginx docs point out](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#allow), the deny rules can be applied to the entire server configuration:

```
Syntax: allow address | CIDR | unix: | all;
Default:    —
Context:    http, server, location, limit_except
```